# Removing % sign from directory names

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a folder `topdir` which contains subfolders like `%foo` or `%bar` but also `foobar`.

Any % signs at the first char should be removed, so that `%foo` gets renamed to `foo`.
There's no need for recursive renaming, only folders inside `topdir` should be renamed.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the directory, rename each directory in turn, but only if the destination doesn't already exist

```
cd topdir &&
  for src in %*
  do
      dst="${src#%}"
      [ -d "$src" ] && [ ! -e "$dst" ] && mv -- "$src" "$dst"
  done
```